# How to get x and y cordinates separately to int from cvPoint?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, gesture-recognition

From the following program, I need to find the x and y value of coordinates from the cvPoint value.

```
for(int i=0; i<nomdef; i++)  
{
    if(defectArray[i].depth > 40 )
    {
        con=con+1;

        cvLine(src, *(defectArray[i].start), *(defectArray[i].depth_point),CV_RGB(255,255,0),1, CV_AA, 0 );  
        cvCircle(src, *(defectArray[i].depth_point), 5, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 2, 8,0);  
        cvCircle(src, *(defectArray[i].start), 5, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2, 8,0);  
        cvLine(src, *(defectArray[i].depth_point), *(defectArray[i].end),CV_RGB(0,255,255),1, CV_AA, 0 );  
        cvDrawContours(src,defects,CV_RGB(0,0,0),CV_RGB(255,0,0),-1,CV_FILLED,8);
    }
}
```

The circle is drawn using the points. I need to get the x and y coordinates from the points. The defect array is created by `CvConvexityDefect* defectArray`.

Answer (score 0):

If name of your point object is myPoint , then you can access its x and y values as

```
int x = myPoint.x ;
int y = myPoint.y ;
```

in your case you can write

```
int x = *(defectArray[i].start).x ; 
int y = *(defectArray[i].start).y ;
```

Comment: request for member ‘x’ in ‘(defectArray + 32u)->CvConvexityDefect::start’, which is of pointer type ‘CvPoint*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
      int x1 = *(defectArray[1].start).x;
i had the error about it.. what should i do ?